# Are questions unlikely to be useful to others permitted?

Tags: discussion, homework-and-exercises

I came to Math and Physics Stack Exchange with a "forum mindset" (partly inherited from Stack Overflow and partly from other math/physics fora), where any problem is welcome, excepting duplicates and do-my-homework questions. I then proceeded to mostly ask questions such as these four: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3171551/longest-path-through-a-rectangular-board), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3275000/how-many-legal-positions-are-there-on-a-rubiks-cube-with-two-pieces-glued-toget), [3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/564126/collision-of-constrained-spheres), [4](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/568997/helium-balloon-energy-gain). They were problems either connected to projects I worked on or just wonderings.

Such questions are like homework in that they are specific (as opposed to modular - naturally arising in many situations), but, unlike homework, there is not necessarily an easily achievable solution. I asked them because I had no clue how to even approach them. But, since other people are unlikely to wonder about the same setup as I do, the questions will at most serve a pedagogical purpose if some interesting underlying concept is involved.

None of these questions were closed, but now, reading through the homework policy, I am not sure whether such a type of question is welcome. I am asking specifically about Physics SE, using the math questions only to provide more examples of the underlying concept.

Comment: Math is special because the count of the interesting, essentially different problems is $\aleph_0$.

Comment: *"None of these questions were closed, but now, reading through the homework policy, I am not sure whether such a type of question is welcome."* - both your questions have incurred close votes as homework-like after you posted this question and the close reviews are ongoing, and I don't really see what distinguishes this from "usual" homework-like questions except the *level* of the problem.

Comment: Your "forum mindset" could be problematic. Stack Exchange is a set of Q&A sites, not a forum. Stack Overflow isn't a forum either. People coming to a Q&A with a forum-mindset tend to get disappointed.

Comment: @Mast I think this self-representation of the SE is what made it so big, so useful, so evil - and to the best forum of the internet. I am here since 6 years, and I believe it is a HQ forum. I never believed, neither accepted this "we are not a forum" thing.